# How can I update records in sphinx search index by sql query?

Tags: sphinx

I have a problem when I want update record in sphinx search index

```
mysql> UPDATE indexname SET field = 'value' where id = 295;

ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT (or 3 other tokens) near ''value' where id = 295'
```

Is it possible to update some text field in disk index (not RT)

My sphinx version is: 2.1.7-id64-release (rel21-r4638)

Thanks for some ideas:)

Answer (score 5):

No. You can ***not*** update a `Field` in a RT index.

To 'update' a `Field`, you need to delete the whole row, and re-insert it fresh. There is a `REPLACE INTO` command to do both in one step.

---

Only `attributes` can be updated. (Early versions of sphinx can't update ***string*** attributes, ie only update numeric attributes, but I think the very latest version has gained the ablity to update even string attributes. )

---

Edit, actully notice now you mention disk-indexes, not RT indexes. Still can't update `Field`s (ie neither on RT or disk-indexes)

Again you can update some attributes, with some restrictions, see http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-updateatttributes
(not sure the latest support for updating string attributes on RT indexes, is even extended to disk-indexes)

... in short UPDATE works pretty much the same on both disk and RT indexes. RT indexes just have INSERT/REPLACE/DELETE which you can't use at all with disk indexes.